# How to increase value of particular row with one?

Tags: sql, web-sql

I have a table named `menu_click_count` on the front end. It has two columns which is `name` and `count`. `name` column has the names of fields like `dashboard`,`travellers`,`hotels`,etc. Now I want to update any of these fields so that the `count` value for that row should be increased by one.

I have already inserted names of fields. Now what I am trying to do is to update the count field by one. Here count fields contains a number

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS menu_click_count(name,count)
INSERT INTO menu_click_count (name) VALUES ('dashboard')
INSERT INTO menu_click_count (name) VALUES ('travellers')
INSERT INTO menu_click_count (name) VALUES ('flight')
INSERT INTO menu_click_count (name) VALUES ('hotels')
INSERT INTO menu_click_count (name) VALUES ('trips')
```

When I update a row I can use update query but it will be static and I want it to be dynamic so that it increases it's own value by one on update query. Is there any optimum way to do this dynamically

Comment: UPDATE table SET cnt=cnt+1 WHERE xxx='zzz';

Comment: Can you post it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET cnt=cnt+1 WHERE xxx='zzz';
```